# How does a Bayesian Linear Regression work on a non-randomized data set of traffic intensities?

Tags: algorithm, azure, machine-learning, linear-regression, bayesian

I am trying to predict the *intensities* of each lane for the next 15 minutes (a part of my thesis research). I have a data set with the intensities of each lane of each 15 minutes of the past 3 months. I have used 6 different Machine Learning algorithms in **Azure Machine Learning** to check which one predicts the most accurately. I picked the Bayesian Linear Regression to describe the algorithm and what it does step-by-step.

It is still unclear to me how the algorithm works, because I am not good in detailed maths. This is why I used a cloud-computing ready Machine Learning tool to do the work for me. I have seen some sources and explanations on the internet, but they are all too mathematical to me and I still don't get it.

My trained model looks like this when I click on '`Visualize`':
[image]

[image]

My evaluation model:
[image]

My question is if someone would like to explain the ***Bayesian Linear Regression*** algorithm like I'm a **dummy**. And why do the multiple other features of the data set that I included in the algorithm, influence the prediction?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should start learning what is linear regression first then move to Bayesian Linear. The idea of linear regression is to use a function to
draw a line that passes through the middle of your data. Simpler then that without maths would be hard to explain.

[Linear Regression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkRgs.png)
Linear Regression
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPG4NjIkCjc

Comment: Thank you. I am already trying to fully understand what exactly the Linear Regression does. It makes sense of course.